# memory issue when trying to buffer/union large dataset using postgis

Tags: postgis, buffer, large-datasets, memory, union

I am trying to generated a dissolved buffer of a large point dataset (Ideally 29 million points - Address data in Great-Britain, but I receive the data by chunks of 1 million points, so these could be used instead).

After trying (and obviously failing!) different methods using ArcGIS, I came across this article:
http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2009/01/must-faster-unions-in-postgis-14.html

Since I have been willing to try postgis for a while a gave this a go. Obviously being an absolute beginner I struggled a bit to get the whole thing up and running, but I finally managed to import data and buffer it. I am struggling however with the ST_Union call, because of memory issues (I am using postgis 2.0.1 running on pretty old 32bits windows pc with little scope to change that in the near future).

I tried changing the memory settings of postgres, as described in the question below:
[Queries returning very big datasets in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/queries-returning-very-big-datasets-in-postgis)

I believe I also created a spatial index properly on my geometry column. As far as I can tell, it didn't help.

I managed to run ST_Union on a 500 000 points subset, which is already pretty big. I think at that point the best for me might be to try using the Declare/Fetch method mentioned in the above question, however being a complete beginner I am having difficulties.

I believe it is in my interest to keep the slices as big as possible (because the ST_Union algorithm is fast and optimised). I think I would therefore just need to find a way to "slice" my ST_Union() queries to output one multipolygon for each 500000 rows. I would then be just one ST_Union on the resulting multipolygons away from the holy grail...

It is also possible that my query is sub-optimal. Or, there might by another great simple solution that I just haven't thought about or found online yet...

Here is a query I am currently using:

```
    drop table if exists ab_buffer_unioned;
    create table ab_buffer_unioned (
    gid serial primary key
    , the_geom geometry
    );

    insert into
        ab_buffer_unioned (the_geom)
    select
        st_Union(the_geom)
    from
        (select the_geom from ab_buffer limit 500000) as absubset;
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix my issues, or modify that query to add a loop or a cursor?

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

Many thanks to Paul for his suggestion below. The GeoHash trick worked great as can be seen below (see how the cluster size varies with the population density!)
[image: ST_Union applied to slices of data sorted by GeoHash]

Comment: running on pretty old 32bits windows pc - you are hitting the limitation of the operating system. This should work in PostGIS without to much issue - recommend a linux based 64 bit postgis, fast disk 15,000rpm and lots of RAM 8/16GB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be trying to union all the shapes without any use of attributes to group, which is odd, but taking that as a given... you want to try and union things that are close together first. So

```
CREATE SEQUENCE bseq;

WITH ordered AS (
  SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 10) AS geom
  FROM points
  ORDER BY ST_GeoHash(geom)
),
grouped AS (
  SELECT nextval('bseq') / 100000 AS id, ST_Union(geom) AS geom
  FROM ordered
  GROUP BY id
)
groupedfinal AS (
  SELECT ST_Union(geom) AS geom
  FROM grouped
)
SELECT * FROM groupedfinal;
```

You might still run out of memory since you're building one ultra huge geometry from millions of inputs. If you do actually have grouping that results in a smaller feature I'm sure things could be finessed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I do have 1 attribute I could use in a group by clause, but I suspect it won't help much (only 2 values in the field, and the split is 90% / 10%). If spliting the multipolygon in individual polygons using ST_Dump or similar would help I can definitely do it, but from what I can tell this would happen after the massive multigeometry is created anyway so not sure it would help? also, my geometries are not in lat-long, so if I want to use geohash I believe I need to convert the coordinates first... is there an alternative?

Comment: Just wrap in a call to transform, ST_GeoHash(ST_Transform(geom, 4326))

Comment: Thanks Paul. Your solution worked (almost) perfectly. It is a bit slow to run on my server (I think I still have work to do to optimise memory usage, it now never ramps up!) but it does the job! I had to remove the last step (groupedfinal) because for some reason it crashes (Error message: GEOSUnaryUnion: St9bad_alloc - even though I call ST_Union not ST_UnaryUnion, and even if I ST_Dump() the multipolygons before the final union to simplify the geometries). However I managed to run that step separately in arcgis so that is not a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

While it appears to be possible to do it completely in PostGIS [easily](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS), in such cases I would likely just whip together a brief batch script to do the [OFFSET](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html) incrementing. It's a bit trickier on windows, but the general syntax idea is:

```
FOR %BATCH IN (0 500000 ... last_offset) DO psql.exe ...
```

For a better hint about invocation and avoiding password prompting, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016730/postgres-psql-and-a-bat-file).

Comment: Thanks. This looks pretty simple indeed. I will fall back to this if my attempts are doing it through a sql loop fail (quite likely given my level!)